# Cannot run any ggsubplot examples

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to run the example from the `geom_subplot` help page from the `ggsubplot` package.

```
library(ggplot2)
devtools::install_github('ggsubplot', 'garrettgman')
library(ggsubplot)

ggplot(nasa) +
  geom_subplot(aes(long, lat, group = id,
    subplot = geom_point(aes(surftemp, temperature), size = 1/4))) +
  coord_map()
```

And I get the following error:

```
Error in layout_base(data, vars, drop = drop) : 
  At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting
```

This same error occurs with with every ggsubplot example I've tried to run so far. I've tried with both the CRAN and github version of ggsubplot. I would bet this is an incompatibility with the newest version of ggplot2 but I don't know enough about ggplot development to diagnose it myself.

```
R.version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          1.0                         
year           2014                        
month          04                          
day            10                          
svn rev        65387                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
nickname       Spring Dance 

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggsubplot_0.3.1 ggplot2_0.9.3.1 devtools_1.5   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.4     evaluate_0.5.5   grid_3.1.0       gtable_0.1.2     httr_0.3         labeling_0.2     MASS_7.3-32     
 [9] memoise_0.2.1    munsell_0.4.2    parallel_3.1.0   plyr_1.8.1       proto_0.3-10     Rcpp_0.11.1      RCurl_1.95-4.1   reshape2_1.4    
[17] scales_0.2.4     stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.1.0      whisker_0.3-2
```

Comment: does `str(nasa)` show a structure with those corresponding fields?

Comment: Your code runs for me (R 3.0.3 64bit running on Win 7, fresh session). Have you tried restarting R?

Comment: thanks for the comments, `str(nasa)` is fine, it shows all the necessary columns. And I was able to run my code in R 3.0.3, so this seems to be an issue with ggsubplot and R 3.1.0, or perhaps the version of ggplot2 corresponding to R 3.1.0.

Comment: I had the same problems with R 3.1.0. thank you for sharing!

Comment: I posted an issue in github: https://github.com/garrettgman/ggsubplot/issues/10

Answer (score 1):

It seems that package `ggsubplot` no longer is maintained.

[Message on CRAN (as of 2016-12-23)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggsubplot/index.html):

> Package ‘ggsubplot’ was removed from the CRAN repository.
>
> Formerly available versions can be obtained from the archive.
>
> Archived on 2016-01-11 as requested by the maintainer garrett@rstudio.com.

On GitHub (https://github.com/garrettgman/ggsubplot), the last commit dates back to 2015-07-09.

Installation from GitHub under R 3.3.2 with `devtools::install_github('garrettgman/ggsubplot')` failed with an error message complaining about missing function `eval`.