# Does ggsubplot work with R 3.2.1+?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The version of ggsubplot available from CRAN is incompatible with recent versions of R (e.g 3.1.1), and running the ggsubplot examples returns an error about

```
Error in layout_base(data, vars, drop = drop) : 
  At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting
```

It's a problem people have noted in StackOverflow questions:

- [Cannot run any ggsubplot examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480711/cannot-run-any-ggsubplot-examples)
  [Plotting bar chart on map using ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23927709/plotting-bar-chart-on-map-using-ggplot2/23931358#23931358)

and GitHub issues:

- https://github.com/garrettgman/ggsubplot/issues/14
  https://github.com/garrettgman/ggsubplot/issues/10

However, the GitHub issues were closed earlier this month (2015-07-09), which made me optimistic that ggsubplot would would work with R 3.2.1+

[CRAN hosts version 0.3.2 of ggsubplot (released 2013-12-14)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggsubplot/index.html) so I used package `devtools` to install ggsubplot from GitHub.

I tried to run the Afghanistan casualties example code, but I'm getting a different error now:

```
Error in get(x, envir = this, inherits = inh)(this, ...) : 
  could not find function "aesply"
```

Is there something I can do to make this work?

Also, how do I confirm which version of ggsubplot I'm using?

The code I tried follows:

```
## install.packages("devtools")

library(devtools)

dev_mode(on=T)

install_github("garrettgman/ggsubplot")

library(ggplot2)
## library(ggsubplot) - I just loaded this, right?
library(maps)
library(plyr)

# getbox by Heike Hoffman, 
# https://github.com/ggobi/paper-climate/blob/master/code/maps.r
getbox <- function (map, xlim, ylim) {
  # identify all regions involved
  small <- subset(map, (long > xlim[1]) & (long < xlim[2]) & (lat > ylim[1]) & (lat < ylim[2]))
  regions <- unique(small$region)
  small <- subset(map, region %in% regions)  

  # now shrink all nodes back to the bounding box
  small$long <- pmax(small$long, xlim[1])
  small$long <- pmin(small$long, xlim[2])
  small$lat <- pmax(small$lat, ylim[1])
  small$lat <- pmin(small$lat, ylim[2])

  # Remove slivvers
  small <- ddply(small, "group", function(df) {
    if (diff(range(df$long)) < 1e-6) return(NULL)
    if (diff(range(df$lat)) < 1e-6) return(NULL)
    df
  })

  small
}


## map layer
## adapted from map_nasa:
# https://github.com/ggobi/paper-climate/blob/master/code/maps.r

# assembling data
world <- map_data("world")

# building afghanistan layer
afghanistan <- getbox(world, c(60,75), c(28, 39))
map_afghanistan <- list(
  geom_polygon(aes(long, lat, group = group), data = afghanistan, 
               fill = "white", colour = "black", inherit.aes = FALSE, 
               show_guide = FALSE),
  scale_x_continuous("", breaks = NULL, expand = c(0.02, 0)),
  scale_y_continuous("", breaks = NULL, expand = c(0.02, 0)))


## 2d bin with bar chart subplots displaying data in each region
ggplot(casualties) +
  map_afghanistan +
  geom_subplot2d(aes(lon, lat,
                     subplot = geom_bar(aes(victim, ..count.., fill = victim))),
                 bins = c(15,12), ref = NULL, width = rel(0.8)) +
  coord_map()+
  theme(legend.position = "right")
```

Comment: In my case (and I use a much older R version!) it only works if I reinstall the ggsubplot package with every new session.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that package `ggsubplot` no longer is maintained.

[Message on CRAN (as of 2016-12-23)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggsubplot/index.html):

> Package ‘ggsubplot’ was removed from the CRAN repository.
>
> Formerly available versions can be obtained from the archive.
>
> Archived on 2016-01-11 as requested by the maintainer garrett@rstudio.com.

On GitHub (https://github.com/garrettgman/ggsubplot), the last commit dates back to 2015-07-09.

Installation from GitHub under R 3.3.2 with `devtools::install_github('garrettgman/ggsubplot')` failed with an error message complaining about missing function `eval`.