# I want to plot a point pattern that is marked by a function (in R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, spatial

I have a time series dataset with spatial data (x,y coordinates). Each point is static in location, but its value varies over time, ie. each point has its own unique function. I want to assign these functions as a mark, so I can plot the point pattern with each individual time series as a plotting symbol.
This is an exploratory step to eventually perform some spatial functional data analysis. 
As an example, I want something like Figure 2 published in this article:
*Delicado,P., R. Giraldo, C. Comas, and J. Mateu. 2010. Spatial Functional Data: Some Recent Contibutions. Environmetrics 21:224-239
I'm having trouble posting an image of the figure

1) Working in R with ggplot2, I can plot a line of change in quant of each id over time:

```
(Fake example dataset, where x and y are Carteian coordinates, id is an    individual observation, and quant are values of id at each year):

x<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
y<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
year<-c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
id<-c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c")
quant<-c(5,2,4,2,4,2,4,4,6)
allData<-data.frame(x,y,year,id,quant)

ggplot(allData,aes(x=year,y=quant, group=id))+geom_line()
```

2) Or I can plot the geographic point pattern of id:

```
ggplot(allData,aes(x=x,y=y,color=id))+geom_point()
```

I want to plot the graph from (2), but use the line plots from (1) as the point symbols (marks). Any suggestions?

Comment: Package `ggsubplot`?  For awhile it's only worked in [R versions < 3.1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480711/cannot-run-any-ggsubplot-examples) but the development version [may work now](https://github.com/garrettgman/ggsubplot/issues/10). I haven't tried it.

Comment: Yep that's it. Still only works on old versions. Thanks